# Moving image with mouse Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jframe

Okay I am fairly new to Java and am having problems on a project that was assigned to me. I am having trouble moving my CTetrimino object across the JFrame
Here is my CTetrimino class.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class CTetriMino {

public CTetriMino(int type, int x, int y, int w, int h, Color c) 
{
    CMino m = new CMino();
    d = m.getDiameter();
    Type=type;
    X=x;
    Y=y;
    Width=w;
    Height=h;
    FillColor=c;
}

public CTetriMino(CTetriMino src) { // copy constructor
    Type=src.Type;
    X=src.X;
    Y=src.Y;
    Width=src.Width;
    Height=src.Height;
    FillColor=src.FillColor;
}

public int getX() { return X; }
public void setX(int x) { X=x; }
public int getY() { return Y; }
public void setY(int y) { Y=y; }

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(FillColor);
    switch (Type) {
    case 0:
        //g.fillOval(X, Y, Width, Height);
        //break;
        g.fillOval(X, Y, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X+d,Y, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X+d,Y-d, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X+d+d,Y-d, d, d);
        break;
    case 1:
        g.fillRect(X, Y, Width, Height);
        //g.fillOval(X, Y, d, d);
        //g.fillOval(X+d,Y, d, d);
        //g.fillOval(X+d,Y+d, d, d);
        //g.fillOval(X+d+d,Y+d, d, d);
        break;
    case 2:
        g.fillOval(X, Y, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X+d,Y, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X,Y-d, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X+d,Y-d, d, d);
        break;
    case 3:
        g.fillOval(X, Y, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X,Y+d, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X,Y+d+d, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X,Y-d, d, d);
        break;
    case 4:
        g.fillOval(X, Y, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X,Y+d, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X,Y-d, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X+d,Y-d, d, d);
        break;
    case 5:
        g.fillOval(X, Y, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X,Y+d, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X,Y-d, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X-d,Y-d, d, d);
        break;
    case 6:
        g.fillOval(X, Y, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X+d,Y, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X,Y-d, d, d);
        g.fillOval(X-d,Y, d, d);
        break;
        }
    }

public boolean containPoint(int x, int y) {
        switch (Type) {
        case 0:
            {
                double a=Width/2.0;
                double b=Height/2.0;
                double xc=X+a;
                double yc=Y+b;
                System.out.println(a);
                System.out.println(b);
                System.out.println(xc);
                System.out.println(yc);
                System.out.println(((x-xc)*(x-xc)/(a*a)+(y-yc)*(y-yc)/(b*b)<=1.0));
                return ((x-xc)*(x-xc)/(a*a)+(y-yc)*(y-yc)/(b*b)<=1.0);

            }
        case 1:
            return (x>=X && y>=Y && x<X+Width && y<Y+Height);

        }

        return false;
    }





private int Type;   
private int X;
private int Y;
private int Width;
private int Height;
private Color FillColor;
private int d;
}
```

Here is my Panel class which I add to the Jframe in a TestNewTetris class.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;



public class Panel extends JPanel 
implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{


private ArrayList<CTetriMino> originals;  
private ArrayList<CTetriMino> duplicates;

private CTetriMino BlockToBeMoved;
private int m_nOffsetX; // difference between cursor and top-left corner
private int m_nOffsetY;

// double buffering
private Image backBuffer;
private Graphics gBackBuffer;

boolean isInitialized;

// init and register mouse event handler
public Panel()
{
    isInitialized=false;
    // handle mouse and mouse motion events
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

// Set up the initial state after the panel is created
void init()
{
    // Initial state
    duplicates = new ArrayList<CTetriMino>();
    originals = new ArrayList<CTetriMino>();
    Color[] colors = {Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.magenta, Color.cyan, Color.yellow, Color.orange};
    int count=colors.length;
    int dx=10;
    int dy=30;
    int gap=20;
    int length=(getSize().height-2*dy-(count-1)*gap)/count;
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) { 
        //originals.add(new CTetriMino((i<count/2)?0:1, dx, dy+i*(length+gap), length, length, colors[i]));
        System.out.println(length);
        originals.add(new CTetriMino(i, dx, dy, length, length, colors[i])); 
        dx = dx+110;

    }
    BlockToBeMoved=null; // no shape selected

    // create the back buffer
    backBuffer = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
    gBackBuffer = backBuffer.getGraphics();
}

// State Presentation
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    // super.paintComponent( g ); // clears drawing area

    if (!isInitialized) {
        isInitialized=true;
        init();
    }
    // State Presentation, using double buffers
    // First, clear the back buffer
    gBackBuffer.setColor(Color.white);
    gBackBuffer.clearRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    // draw the originals to back buffer
    for (int i=0; i<originals.size(); i++) {
        originals.get(i).draw(gBackBuffer);
    }
    // draw the duplicates to back buffer
    for (int i=0; i<duplicates.size(); i++) {
        duplicates.get(i).draw(gBackBuffer);
    }
    // copy from back buffer to front
    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, null);
    g.fillRect(0, 100, 800, 4);
    g.fillRect(0, 400, 800, 4);
} // end method paintComponent

// MouseListener event handlers
public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e )
{
    if (e.isMetaDown()) {   // right button
        for (int i=duplicates.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if (duplicates.get(i).containPoint(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                duplicates.remove(i);
                repaint();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e )
{
    if (e.isMetaDown()) return; // ignore right button

    // First, check the originals, from top down (i.e. back to front)
    for (int i=duplicates.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        CTetriMino p=duplicates.get(i);
        if (p.containPoint(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
            duplicates.remove(i);
            duplicates.add(p);  // move to the end, i.e. the top
            BlockToBeMoved=p;
            m_nOffsetX=e.getX()-BlockToBeMoved.getX();
            m_nOffsetY=e.getY()-BlockToBeMoved.getY();
            repaint();
            return;
        }
    }
    // Second, check the orginals 
    for (int i=originals.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        CTetriMino p=originals.get(i);
        System.out.println(p.containPoint(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        if (p.containPoint(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
            CTetriMino p2=new CTetriMino(p); // make a copy of p
            duplicates.add(p2); // add to the end
            BlockToBeMoved=p2;  // p2 is selected, to be moved
            m_nOffsetX=e.getX()-BlockToBeMoved.getX();
            m_nOffsetY=e.getY()-BlockToBeMoved.getY();
            repaint();
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e )
{
    BlockToBeMoved=null; // no shape selected
}

public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e )
{
}

public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e )
{
}

public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e )
{
}

public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e )
{
    if (e.isMetaDown()) return; // ignore right button
    System.out.println(BlockToBeMoved);
    if (BlockToBeMoved!=null) {
        BlockToBeMoved.setX(e.getX()-m_nOffsetX);
        BlockToBeMoved.setY(e.getY()-m_nOffsetY);
        repaint();
    }

} // end method mouseDragged






}
```

I would show what my program does when I run it but I do not have a high enough reputation yet.

The bottom Jframe is what is compiled if I change this code:

```
case 0:
g.fillOval(X, Y, d, d);
g.fillOval(X+d,Y, d, d);
g.fillOval(X+d,Y-d, d, d);
g.fillOval(X+d+d,Y-d, d, d);
break;
```

to this:

```
case 0:
g.fillOval(X, Y, Width, Height);
break;
```

In both variants I am able to drag the green square. In the second variant I am able to drag the red circle. I CAN'T however move my red tetrimino. I am simply wondering why I cannot move my red tetrimino. Eventually I want to be able to move all of the tetriminos and drag them under the second black line to delete them. I also want to be able to rotate the tetriminos by pressing righr click. Any code or advice is appreciated. If you need more information I will provide it asap. 
Thanks.

Comment: There are ***many*** examples of using Swing to allow the dragging of graphics with a mouse to be found on this site, some written by me and MadProgrammer among others. You will want to search this site and study these examples.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I looked at a lot of examples and am still having trouble. I am able to move one circle but not a combination of 4 little circles. If you could take a look at my code again I would be so thankful.

Comment: I have tried looking at your code but am running into road-blocks. 1) It is formatted poorly making it hard to read. We are volunteers putting in effort on our own free time, and we appreciate it greatly if you do likewise and put in effort when asking your question to make it easy to understand, which includes posting code that is well formatted and conforms to general Java formatting standards (which you can find easily via Google). 2) I can't run your code because it is not fully self-contained, not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- please check the link.

Comment: I completely understand. Although you did not answer my question, you helped me greatly. I will try to make my next questions easier to understand next time.

Comment: +1 for your learning effort in StackOverflow - welcome on board!

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly the solution should be like this below.
Please create image package like below.You need to two events for  label mouse dragged , label mouse pressed to do that. Add icon to label it should be image your image.

[image]

[image]

**critical imports**

```
    import java.awt.Point;
```

**events**

```
   private void jLabel1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
          initialClick = evt.getPoint();
    }  





     private void jLabel1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

        int thisX = jLabel1.getLocation().x;
        int thisY = jLabel1.getLocation().y;

        // Determine how much the mouse moved since the initial click
        int xMoved = (thisX + evt.getX()) - (thisX + initialClick.x);
        int yMoved = (thisY + evt.getY()) - (thisY + initialClick.y);

        // Move picture to this position
        int X = thisX + xMoved;
        int Y = thisY + yMoved;

        jLabel1.setLocation(X, Y);
        jLabel1.repaint();


    }
```

Comment: +1 for beautiful answer.I used this way in my paint app but I compared with mini problem.After locating the image with mouse I want to get screen capture for drawing area (movable picture + spaces),after taking screenShot via Robot() the label is doesn't appear in the photo(screen capture) only gaps appear.Do you have any idea about this? Thankyou so much